# IntelliJ IDEA left column can't set breakpoint

Tags: intellij-idea, breakpoints

Why does my IDEA's left column look like this? I can not set a line breakpoint by click and there is also no space for it.

[image]

Comment: Did you try ⌘F8. Alternatively check Run->toggle line breakpoint or corresponding hotkey is working for you. Also, which  community edition you are using.

Comment: Please attach screenshot showing full IDE frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only set breakpoints on "recognized" source files, e.g. you can set breakpoints in a .java-File if inside a configured source folder, either by following the default naming convention, or by configuring the path in the relevant setup dialog. You can not set breakpoints in, say, a properties file. Basically, if you can run it in your IDE, you should very much be able to set break points.

As for the "why does it look like this", do you mean the line numbers? You could get rid of those by right click & uncheck "show line numbers".